# apache camel doesn't stop and query database rows multiple times

Tags: apache-camel, shutdown

i'm setting up a pipeline from oracle database (which has a table containing xml type column) to mongoDB using apache camel. My problem is that if i include value 2000ms to thread.sleep(2000) the route stopped running and got shutdown in the middle of polling rows, i changed that value to Integer.MAX_VALUE, i found that each row was added multiple times into mongoDB. I'm totally new on this framework, so I was thinking that you might help with it !

Here's camel-context.xml:

```
<camelContext id="camelContext-f0b5f69c-a9b5-434a-974b-6fe815aa3d06" 
 xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
    <!-- here is a sample which processes the input files
     (leaving them in place - see the 'noop' flag)
     then performs content based routing on the message using XPath -->
    <threadPool id="myPool" maxPoolSize="25" maxQueueSize="200"
        poolSize="20" threadName="Cool"/>
    <route id="jdbc_connect"  streamCache="true">
        <from uri="timer://foo"/>
        <to id="_to3" uri="sql:SELECT * FROM Schema.Park ? 
dataSource=#dataSource&amp;outputType=StreamList"/>
        <split executorServiceRef="myPool" id="_split1"
            parallelProcessing="true" stopOnException="true" 
            streaming="true">
            <simple>${in.body}</simple>
            <process id="_process1" ref="rowProcessor"/>
            <unmarshal id="_unmarshal1">
                <jaxb contextPath="OracleMongo.Orcl.JAXB"/>
            </unmarshal>
            <marshal id="_marshal1">
                <json library="Gson"/>
            </marshal>
            <convertBodyTo id="_convertBodyTo1" type="String"/>
            <to id="_to2" uri="mongodb3:mongoBean? 
        database=test&amp;collection=Park&amp;operation=insert"/>
        </split>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

Here is main class:

```
 public static final void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ApplicationContext appContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
            "META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
    CamelContext camelContext = SpringCamelContext.springCamelContext(
            appContext, false);
    try {
        camelContext.start();
        Thread.sleep(Integer.MAX_VALUE);
    } finally {
        camelContext.stop();
    }
}
```

Here is what i got when i include value 2000ms to Thread.sleep:

```
 thread #2 - ShutdownTask] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  Route: 
 jdbc_connect shutdown complete, was consuming from: timer://foo
 [                          main] DefaultShutdownStrategy        INFO  
 Graceful shutdown of 1 routes completed in 300 seconds
 [                          main] DefaultInflightRepository      WARN  
 Shutting down while there are still 11 inflight exchanges.
```

Comment: If you just want to run the time only 1 time, then set its repeatCount=1. And do you want to stop Camel after it has done this one time?

Comment: Thank you, i've added repeatCount last night and it worked, since i want to execute select query every 12hours, Do you think adding fixedRate=true&period=43200s would be enough ?

Comment: Oh instead of having the JVM sleep for 12h, then maybe look at some kind of process scheduler (like cron on linux) to schedule calling the JVM application to run every 12h. Then you just need the timer with repeat = 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to have your main thread running as a daemon you may use the `Main` class utility just providing the context:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    org.apache.camel.spring.Main main = new org.apache.camel.spring.Main();
    main.setApplicationContextUri("META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml");
    main.run();
}
```

This would execute your routes without worrying to add any `sleep(...)` on your main thread. Of course, since you don't know when your route finish, then you must stop it manually (CTRL+C to signal to JVM), not sure if that is enough for your use case.

About the timer, as Claus suggested in the question comment, just use the repeat option in order to execute it once (by default the timer will tick every second starting up the route indefinitely):

```
<from uri="timer://foo?repeatCount=1"/>
```

Hope that helps.